# CI/CD with pnpm workspaces + lerna 7.x

Tags: webpack, continuous-integration, monorepo, lerna, pnpm-workspace

I have created a monorepo with pnpm workspaces and Lerna.
The applications live under packages/* and some libraries under lib/*

I have one library under lib that needs to be built before being installed. During development I was able to install dependencies for all packages and build this library manually, but that's not a feasible approach in a pipeline where I want to build and deploy specific applications.

I installed this lib `my-lib` to an application `@myapp/package1` using
`pnpm add my-lib --filter @myapp/package1`.
This causes the dependency to appear as

```json
{
  "name": "@myapp/package1",
  "dependencies": {
     "my-lib": "workspace:^"
  }
}
```

With this, webpack is not able to resolve the paths (any help with this will be appreciated).
So, I've changed it to

```
  "my-lib": "../../lib/my-lib",
```

I'm now unsure, how to install and build dependencies of specific application(s) in pipeline.
Locally, I've tried few commands, but they ignore `my-lib` for some reason.

- Only considers `@myapp/package1`

```bash
npx lerna run build --since HEAD
```

- Again only considers @myapp/package1 and not its dependencies

```bash
npx lerna run build --scope=@myapp/package1
```

- builds all packages, keeping dependency order intact, but I want to limit it to dependencies of specific changed packages.

```bash
npx lerna run build
```

Also how to extend this behavior to `pnpm install` to install dependencies of specific packages. For `@myapp/package1`, it would mean installing dependencies of `mylib` as well.

### Edit

I was able to achieve some of the things asked here:

To build the library before it's installed in another application, I created a postinstall script in the library

```json
{
   "scripts": {
      "postinstall": "pnpm run build"
   }
}
```

To install dependencies of specific package and also the dependencies of its transitive dependencies

```bash
pnpm recursive install --filter @myapp/package1
```

To build a specific package, and before that build all its dependencies

```bash
npx lerna run build --scope=@myapp/package1 --include-dependencies
```